# Option to redirect to 2 different places on form submission

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, forms, google-forms

I looked through the web on submittig forms with jquery/ajax, but I couldnt find my specific problem anywhere. I downloaded a google form and am styling / editing it (in other words, Ihave no control over the server side code and Icannot edit the form action). In the form, I have two radio butons. If one of them iis clicked, I would like the form to submit to google (so I have the results in a google spreadsheet) but I also need it to redirect to a  different page (depending on which button was selected). I assume the only way to do this would be with javascript, so I trid various jquery methods, such as
`$("button").submit();`  but things get complicated because its a downloaded google form. Also, the target is a hidden iframe so it doesnt show the google thank you page. Does anyone have any advice as to how I would go about my problem?

****RESOLVED******
I ended up calling this `onSubmit()` method on the onsubmit attribute of the form:

```
<script>
function redirectPage(url )
{
setTimeout(function() { 
window.location = url;
}, 500);
}
function submitCheck() {
//check if one of the radio buttons is checked
    if(document.getElementById("group_1677476484_1").checked == true) { //
    redirectPage("http://redirect1.com");

    } else {
        redirectPage("http://redirect2.com");

    }

}
</script>
```

The key was adding the setTimeout in the redirectPage method, allowing the page enough time to submit the form before redirecting.

Comment: Does the google form permit sending a javascript function to call when it returns? That could hook you in to what you need to do after the for submission.